# Youtube API - Remove Duplicate Rejected as well as Original copy

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

Every now and then when I push a video through the Youtube API I do not get the success result back to my server with the appropriate video ID. (assuming some kind of random connectivity issue)

This creates an issue where my server assumes the video hasn't uploaded it so it attempts to upload it again. Which then creates a duplicate.

How would I find out and remove any duplicates as well as the 1st uploaded video so I can start the process again and upload a fresh copy?

Is there a way to tell youtube to delete the video if it can not return the ID successfully to my server?

Cheers